# SQL - Making a single row have different values for each different FK

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

so basically (if the title isn't clear), I have a cookbook database which contains tables in the picture below.

Now, there is one thing that bothers me, for example - I have an omelette recipe and pancakes recipe in the **RECIPE** table and needed ingredients in the **INGREDIENTS** table, so here's the problem - both recipes need eggs, but an omelette may need 4 eggs (Quantity is actually in grams in the database so about 200g) and pancakes may need 3 eggs (150g).

How can I make the row which has eggs as the ingredient have different values for each recipe? Adding eggs multiple times and having different values for it in the **INGREDIENTS** table wouldn't work because it wouldn't be normalized. I've made a many-to-many relation with a table called **QUANTITY** and entered some values like 100g, 200g, 300g but still, It wouldn't work because I can only connect eggs to a single value.

Hope you understood, haha

Thanks in advance!

[DATABASE RELATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IazIG.png)

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/eIMuvOp.png) --> INGREDIENTS TABLE

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/36oX0hs.png) --> RECIPE TABLE

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/q5G4jgX) --> QUANTITY TABLE

Comment: Dont add comments, just update your answer

Comment: You need a table between the Recipe and the Ingredients table, perhaps called RecipeIngredients. The table should have 3 columns: the Primary Key of the Recipe table, and the Primary Key of the Ingredients table, and the quantity of the ingredients.  If you want to have other details about the recipe, like calorie count, protein count, etc. , you'd list those attributes in your Ingredients table. Then sum accordingly.

Comment: Your `HAVE` table, which associates ingredients with recipes, needs a column expressing the quantity of the given ingredient in the given recipe.

Comment: Looks like your HAVE table is the RecipeIngredients table - I'd add a Quantity column to that table, and remove the QUANTITY table.  Also seems you do not need the CONTAINS table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose the following tables:

**recipes** more or less as it is

**recipe-ingredients** with fields:

*recipeID* - linked with table **recipes** 
*ingredientID* - linked with table **ingredients** 
*quantity* - to hold the quantity

**ingredients** to hold a list of all potential ingredients that can be used in recipes. This has an added benefit, that you can keep the nutritional values here too!. With fields:

*ID* - identifier of an ingredient (integer)
*ingredient_name*
*ingredient_kcal_per_unit* - & other similar fields for fat, carbs, protein etc.
*unitID* - holds the identifier of a unit of measure

**units** to hold all relevant units of measure, like grams, ml, pieces etc. with fields:

*ID* - identifier of the unit (integer)
*unit_name* - the name of the unit

This will allow you to specify for each recipe, which ingredients are used in it, in what quantity, and with a relevant unit of measure: flour in grams, milk in mililiters, eggs in pieces etc. And you can calculate the nutritional values by multiplying the value per unit by quantity.

I hope you can work out the joins yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the relations are not correct.

Since the quantity is a trait of the "ingredient that a recipe has" the best would be to remove the `Quantity` table and make it an attribute of the `Have` table. The calories would be then an attribute of `Ingredients` as in calories per 100g.

The schema would be:

**Recipe**: id_recipe, name

**Have**: id_recipe, id_ingredient, quantity

**Ingredient**: id_ingredient, name, calories

And you can query the recipes and quantities with:

```
SELECT *, Have.Quantity * Ingredient.calories as total_calories
FROM Recipe
LEFT JOIN Have ON Recipe.id_recipe = Have.id_recipe
LEFT JOIN Ingredient ON Ingredient.id_ingredient = Have.id_ingredient;
```

Comment: Why does there seem to be a focus on calories? All I seem to see per the question is a request for Quantity.

Comment: It's secondary to the main question, but I included it in Ingredients to show where all the values of the deleted table could go.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table `INGREDIENT_QTY`

```
  RECIPE: recipe_id, ingredient_id FK --> INGREDIENTS(ingredient_id)
  INGREDIENT_QTY: recipe_id, ingredient_id, QTY FK --> RECIPE (recipe_id, ingredient_id)
```

If you need recipe calories, you need create a calculated column to get that value from `INGREDIENT_QTY`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should provide you the bare minimum.

With this in place, I think you can safely remove these tables (per your picture): **HAVE** & **CONTAINS** & **QUANTITY**.

```
Table Recipes
 [Id]     [int]          NOT NULL
,[Recipe] [VARCHAR] (50) NOT NULL

Table Ingredients
 [Id]          [int]          NOT NULL
,[Ingredient]  [VARCHAR] (50) NOT NULL
,[GramWeight]  [int]          NOT NULL

Table RecipeIngredients
 [RecipeId]     [int]  NOT NULL
,[IngredientId] [int]  NOT NULL
,[Quantity]     [int]  NOT NULL
```